# Disable create data table button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, datatable

I am trying to disable the #test button after one click in a create data table. The problem here is that I can disable it at the start but not after a click.

```
viewPending: function() {
    createDataTable("#pTable",
    {
        "ajax":"test.php",
        "columns": [
    {
              "data": "id",
              "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
             $("#test").on('click', function(){ //enables click event
                    $("#test").off('click');
                    $("#test").prop('disabled', true);
                    //alert("hello");
                    });

                    return '<div id="test" style="text-align: center"> <a id="test" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="'+app.api+'admin/investor/approve/'+ data  +'">' + 'Approve' + '</a></div>';                      
              }
            }   
        ]
    });
},
```

Comment: that's a problem with multiple elements having the same ID I guess (it's a guess because your return value has multiple elements with the same ID)

Comment: even if i have given an id to either of the <div> or <a> it still doesn't work

Comment: I was able to alert ("hello") though

Answer (score 0):

```
  "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
         $(".test").on('click', function(){ //enables click event
            $(this).parent().css("pointer-events","none"); //disable all events of pointer
         });

      return '<div style="text-align: center"> <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm test" href="'+app.api+'admin/investor/approve/'+ data  +'">' + 'Approve' + '</a></div>';                      
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The on click function works only when registered with document.ready function. The same wont work inside the mRender block. Move the onclick function to document.ready function and try.